# Unable to find text on reactjs page with capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I cannot assert any text with the following configuration and screenshots are blank, even though there are no errors and network activity shows 100% success.

#### Versions

- phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.12
- phantomjs 2.1.1
- poltergeist 1.13.0
- capybara 2.12.0

#### Debug logs

[Gist of phantomjs/poltergeist/capybara logs](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/728d9bceabeadf3134ab5223f104f8b3)

#### Symptoms

- captured screenshot and it is transparent
- captured network activity (see gist) successful
- captured html is good (see gist)
- no errors in phantomjs debug (see gist)
- no errors in poltergeist debug (see gist)
- neither long sleeps nor high `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` have no impact on result
- react js works with both manual testing and with selenium/chrome

#### Feature

```
Feature: smoke
  Scenario: Home
    Given I go to the home page
    #When I sleep for 30 seconds
    Then I should see "Landing Page"
```

#### Poltergeist setup

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    js_errors: true,
    timeout: 180,
    debug: true,
    phantomjs: "#{Rails.root}/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs",
    phantomjs_options: %w(--debug=true --load-images=no --proxy-type=none --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=TLSv1),
    window_size: [1280, 600],
    # inspector: true,
    phantomjs_logger: PoltergeistLogger # File.open("target/phantomjs.log", "a")
  })
end
```

#### TLDR;

I have no errors yet a reactjs page doesn't seem to be rendering a DOM within phantomjs or when accessed via poltergeist.

I've run out of options that I'm aware of.  Any thoughts I can try?

Comment: Does any of the JS you are loading use any ES6 features, or has it all been transpiled/polyfilled to a maximum of ES5?  PhantomJS has an issue where certain ES6 features ( `let` for instance) being used in JS at page load won't actually raise an error and it just ignores the JS

Comment: Entirely transpiled to ES5.  I added my .babelrc to the gist just in case you have questions about it.  I'll search for `let` and `const` in the built files and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Ok -- just from the behavior (initial empty html loads, but no other requests are made to the test app) it appears something in the JS isn't running - but if it is the case that PhantomJS has an error but doesn't report it I'm not really sure what to suggest, other than to look through the JS manually and make sure it's what you expected - maybe add some console logs in there to see what is loading and what isn't

Comment: @ThomasWalpole - found a `let` from `camelcase` 4.0.0 in a compiled chunk.  I added it to the gist.  I'll start messing with the `.babelrc` to see how I can get it out and report back.  Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Ah, a few of them and a => function declaration, looks like that might not be being run through babel

Comment: Quite confusing that `camelcase` 4.0.0 is the only problem. Everything else transpiles with webpack/babel, and when I use `try babel` on the camelcase code directly, it also works.  It has no `main` or `module`, wondering if that is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135887/discussion-between-kross-and-thomas-walpole).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: We switched to chrome headless.  In addition, we implemented a few changes in our `visit` navigation to make it more bulletproof (e.g. warmup) based on what we saw locally and on CI.  Here's a gist of our react browsing steps https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/cd58369de1c1395cbd2b96ed142ec606